# Rails Overall Architecture Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very interested to see what Rails veterans on Stack Overflow have to say about this.

Basically, as a Rails newb, and as someone with no "formal" background in programming, one of my biggest challenges has to do with proper architecture. How do I know what the *right* or *better* to build an app are?

I would love to see what some resources are.

I know the basic ones - but a lot of these don't give me the high level architecture overview I want:

[http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Development-Rails-Third-Edition/dp/1934356166/ref=cm_lmf_tit_7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356166)
[http://www.amazon.com/Ruby-Programming-Language-David-Flanagan/dp/0596516177/ref=cm_lmf_tit_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177)
Railscasts

Here's a quick example:

Say I'm building a Rails app that has merchants and shoppers - each set of users has its own authentication, different permissions, etc. Would it be proper to build a single app for this or multiple that communicate through APIs? Is there any added benefit to this multi-app abstraction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this is not an easy question. The complete answer would largely depend on your project.

If you are a starter I'd recommend you keep it all in one app, you have enough "separation" using models wisely. It's hard to immagine a scenario where the complexity introduced by inter-app communication is beneficial.

In your example you should ask yourself wether it's better to use one single parent model for the Merchants and Shoppers or two separate models.

In the former case you can consider STI:

- user (main class, defined as `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`)

  - merchant (defined as `class Merchant < User`)
  - shopper (similarly `class Shopper < User`)

Google for STI for further details.

Then in your controllers/view you can check permissions quickly, for example:

```
if user.class == Merchant
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Similarly the two classes might authenticate with different algorithms. You might also include a "standard" authentication in the base User class and specialize it in the subclasses, if required.

Cheers,